# Issue with projectfolder called (AndroidProjects)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a wired issue. If i set up a folder called `AndroidProjects` and put my project in there... Android-Studio fails with gradle.

one error is:

```
IllegalStateException:
PsiFile not parsed for file D:/AndroidProjects/MyApplication/settings.gradle. 
Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.
```

sometimes it says that gradle has a fatal error....

if i set up my projectlocation to e.g. `andropro` everyting is working fine.

My thoughts:

- may problems with 2 big letters in projectfoldername
- may foldername is to long
- may `android` or `project` are registered words in android-studio

Is there a knowen issue using foldernames like i did above?
couldn't find anything on the net.

Comment: Is it stopping the compilation or execution of program ?

Comment: if gradle doesn't work, of course i can't compile.. so its not really stopping it :)